# How to include value of input feature with the prediction output in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I want to get the Input request included into prediction output in tensorflow.

I have 10 feature column, also i am able to get a prediction of each of the request from test.csv.

How do i get a prediction response including a request in that object, below is my serving input

`def csv_serving_input_fn():
    #Build the Serving Input
    csv_row = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string)
    features,label = _decode_csv(csv_row)
    features.pop(metadata.LABEL_COLUMN)
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features,
                                                    {'csv_row': csv_row})`

`

Comment: Can you precise the desired output ? You want the inputs + the prediction ?

Comment: Yes i want input+prediction in prediction output.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by updating my custom estimator, and thus by not changing the `serving_input_fn`.

Here a snippet of the end of my estimator

```
def ...<custom_estimator>(features, labels, mode, params):
    # generate prediction
    ....
    # Calculate the RMSE/LOSS
    ....
    # Set the return
    predictions_dict = {"predicted": predictions}

    # 4. return EstimatorSpec
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        predictions=predictions_dict,
        loss=loss,
        train_op=train_op,
        eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops,
        export_outputs={
            'predictions': tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(predictions_dict)}
    )
```

In fact, you have to update the `tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput`
I did that in the `set the return` part, I added the inputs in the `predictions_dict`, and it works

```
def ...<custom_estimator>(features, labels, mode, params):
    # generate prediction
    ....
    # Calculate the RMSE/LOSS
    ....
    # Set the return
    predictions_dict = {"inputs":features[TIMESERIES_COL],"predicted": predictions}

    # 4. return EstimatorSpec
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        predictions=predictions_dict,
        loss=loss,
        train_op=train_op,
        eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops,
        export_outputs={
            'predictions': tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(predictions_dict)}
    )
```

Good prediction!!

Comment: Hi Thanks, i tried your way but still getting same                                                      
    `def json_serving_input_fn():
        #Build the Serving Input
        inputs = {}
        for feat in metadata.CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
            inputs[feat] = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string)
        for feat in metadata.NUMERICAL_COLUMNS:
           inputs[feat] = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.float32)
        return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)`

Comment: I'm on holiday, I have few time for working on it. I will post an update ASAP.

Comment: No problem, Thanks i will see if i can find something till then

Comment: Hi. I updated my answer. It works with a custom estimator. Do you also have a custom or not?

Comment: I checked the signature of standard estimators in TF1 and TF2 doc, and it seems impossible to customize the exporter. Thereby, if you don't have a custom estimator, I think that you can't reach your target.